# Afterpage and large figures

Tags: afterpage

I am having trouble using `\afterpage` in combination with some figures+captions that are too adjusted or directly exceed the document's margins (I assume that this is the cause of `\afterpage` not behaving as usual). I don't mind these figures exceeding the margins, but I need to place them close to where they are referenced and they keep being pushed to the end of the document, leaving large empty spaces. Does anybody have a workaround?

The image is an example of what I get, I would like the figure and the caption to be on the second page, and the remaining text in the last page. I have searched the forum, but could not find a suitable solution.

Thank you!

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage[fontsize=9pt]{scrextend}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-3]

*********After page goes here**********

% It works with a short caption:
%
%\afterpage{%
%
%\begin{figure*} 
%   
%   \makebox[\textwidth][c]{
%   
%   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}}
%   
%   \caption[A caption]{Short caption.}
%   
%\end{figure*}
%}

% It does not work with a long caption:

\afterpage{%

\begin{figure*}
    
    \makebox[\textwidth][c]{
    
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}}
    
    \caption[A caption]{\lipsum[1]}
    
\end{figure*}
}

\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: using afterpage that way can only ever make the figure go later in the document. I  wouldn't use `\afterpage` (I wrote it, I know what it does:-) but if you do use it for figures I assume you meant to have `\clearpage` at the end of the argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the form you used, the `\afterpage` could only make the float be further from the point of insertion, or at best have no effect as it delays the insertion but then floats as usual. I would guess you intended `\clearpage` after `\end{figure}` but I would not use `\afterpage` at all here.

Also as it is a single column document, use `figure` not `figure*` (although they are the same) and the `\makebox` does nothing as the image is alreeady scaled to `\textwidth`.

The figure will float until forced out by `\clearpage` as it is too large, latex warns

```
 LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 13.15417pt on input line 43.
```

`\afterpage` does not change that.

You could use `\clearpage` (or `\afterpage{\clearpage}`) but I would simply make the float smaller, 14pt is enough as shown by the warning, then ensure it  is not a top float, so the negative space will not over-print following text.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage[fontsize=9pt]{scrextend}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-3]

*********After page goes here**********


\begin{figure}[bp]
        
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    
    \caption[A caption]{\lipsum[1]}
    
\vspace{-14pt}
\end{figure}


\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer, David. I have learned a lot. :)